# Google Play Games Service Plugin For Unity Issue Not Let Me Choose The Account Intergrating With Gamesparks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games

I face a this problem 3 days. I can't figure it out what mistake i have done.

I have implementG GPGS plugin in unity with gamesparks too. The login goes successful. But something is wierd in here is GPGS do not let me choose an GPGS account even i have 4 account.

**As i know when login with GPGS, the first login will attempt us to let us choose which account will we use to login.**

But in my problem whatever i do, switch account at playstore, switch account at google play games. The First login always use the same account to login.

Example :

I have 4 Account at playstore.

1. A@gmail.com
2. B@gmail.com
3. C@gmail.com
4. D@gmail.com

When i try to login with GPGS, first login always choose **A@gmail.com** to login. When i try to uninstall the game and then try to login. Again always **A@gmail.com** is choose to login. I don't know whats wrong with this. Again i have switch the account at playstore, still i got the same **A@gmail.com** to login. There is not pop up for me at first to choose which want i choose for account.

Below is my code :

```
public void GooglePlusStart()
    {
        //Start the Google Plus Overlay Login

        Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            if(success) {
                log.text = "SUCCESS AUTHENTICATED";
                GooglePlayAuthentication();
            } else{
                log.text = "FAILED AUTHENTICATED";
            }
            //Do something depending on the success achieved
        });

    }

public void GooglePlayAuthentication() {
        if(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated()) {
                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode ((status, code) => {
                    string displayName = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserDisplayName();
                    string email  = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserEmail();
                    new GooglePlayConnectRequest ()
                        .SetCode (code)
                         //.SetAccessToken (PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetAccessToken ())
                        .SetDoNotLinkToCurrentPlayer (false)
                        .SetSwitchIfPossible(true)
                        .SetRedirectUri ("http://www.gamesparks.com/oauth2callback")
                        .SetDisplayName(displayName)
                        .Send ((googleplayAuthResponse) => {
                        if (!googleplayAuthResponse.HasErrors) {
                                Debug.Log (googleplayAuthResponse.DisplayName + " Logged In !");
                                log.text = "SUCCESSSSS    EMAIL : " + email + " ====== Status : " + status + "  ==== Code : " + code + " ====== " + "AccessToken : " + PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetAccessToken () + " ==== " + googleplayAuthResponse.DisplayName + "   :   " + googleplayAuthResponse.UserId + "   :   " + "Logged In! \n " + googleplayAuthResponse.JSONString;
                            } else {
                                Debug.Log ("Failed To Login");
                                log.text = "ERRRRORRRR    EMAIL : " + email + " ====== Status : " + status + " ==== Code : " + code + " ====== " + "AccessToken : " + PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetAccessToken () + " ==== " + googleplayAuthResponse.JSONString;
                            }
                        });
                });
        } else {
            log.text = "Google Play Login Failed";
        }
    }
```

If like this case, Of course i can't transfer my saved game to another device.

What mistake i have done so far ?

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found The Solution.

See the screenshot below :

[image]

When i tick "Enable Google Plus API Access" it worked.